# Making use of what jQuery Collision returns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision-detection, collision

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/

I'm trying to understand how I can use the information that is returned to make changes to different divs. I was originally able to get alerts to pop up when a div collided with the footer2 class, but I couldn't get the CSS to change and for some reason JSFiddle isn't recognizing alerts either. (I assume part of the problem lies with how I linked to jQuery in "External Resources".)

Basically, when sourceforge(dot)net/p/jquerycollision/wiki/Home/#usage says **"Basic usage returns the obstacles that are hit by the colliders"**, how can I make use of that data to make changes to, say, a div's background color.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gogfan/pjhoL899/13/

Relevant snippet:

```
step: function() {

                linkGlobal = $(this);
                var collisions = linkGlobal.collision(".footer2");

                for (var y=0; y<collisions.length; y++)
                {
                    linkGlobal.css("background-color", "yellow");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Looks like it's supposed to give you exactly that: the objects which it collides with. So then you just iterate through the collisions and work with each div like you would any other element.

Comment: Looking at your fiddle code, you're changing the background color on the links divs successfully. Is that not what you were wanting?

Comment: @AndrewWalters - Currently the collision is *suppose* to change the "background-color" of each div that encounters ".footer2" to "yellow". However, at least from what I'M seeing on the browser Pale Moon, nothing changes even when each div collides with .footer2. I'll try it in a different browser, though.

Comment: Here's what I'm seeing in firefox: http://i.stack.imgur.com/roSO1.png

Comment: Yeah, there the divs are still the same colors. I was hoping to get each one to change color to yellow when it hits ".footer2", that red rectangle with a lowered opacity. Any advice on that? Or could you give me an example that makes use of "classical" collision detection in Javascript (checking the bounding boxes and such)?

Comment: Well I was able to get some help using the "old fashioned" method of Javascript collision detection, but I have a problem with that, too; will post a new question, though.